# Updated css file not reflecting in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm working on Laravel framework,

I have changed my `bootstrap.min.css` from **v3** to **v4** but it's not updated in the browser

I have tried:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*/*
```

and I deleted the files from `storage/framework/views` but still, the CSS is not updating.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: If it is in your local machine, please restart the application, remove the browser cache and try again.

Comment: Did you use the same filename? In that case it's probably cached by your browser.

Comment: Try hard refresh `Ctrl + Shft + R`

Comment: You are using `php artisan serve` or `public` path?

Comment: Open your devtools and follow this way: dev tools > network > disable cache
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/9487875

Comment: Thanks for the answers I just cleared my browser history and it's working fine

Answer (score 10):

Just add a query string after end of the css file.Then it will not use cached file css. Like ?v=1,?v=2  or any random string.

Example

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=1a040064279b" >
```

you can also use php function (as marco suggested)

```
?v=echo filemtime();
```

Comment: By doing this you are disabling browser cache completely affecting performance.
You could append the filemtime() of the file (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) instead of time so the parameter only changes on file change

Answer (score 7):

For custom CSS file in laravel, use `time()` function by the following method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/style.css?v=').time()}}">
```

Remember **?v=** is just used for getting value by the `time()` function that will generate random number every time when you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Chrome's cache. Just follow these steps:

1,
**Control+Shift+I**

2,
Click **Network** > Tick **Disable cache**

[image]

3, **Reload** Chrome!!